# Is there an easier way than an "elseif marathon"?

Tags: lua

How do I optimize this code?

```
variable = 1

moveLine = function ()

    if variable == 1 then

        first = color_1.color
        second = color_2.color

    elseif variable == 2 then

        first = color_2.color
        second = color_3.color
    end

variable = variable + 1

end
```

The function is alot longer and that is why I could use an easier way :)

Comment: So... a lot of colors? I think Lua supports arrays.

Comment: @user1173675 You can store the `color_`s in an array and then assign them to `first` and `second` using a function of `variable` to calculate the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be storing your colors in an array:

```
colors = { all your colors }

moveLine = function()
    first = colors[variable]
    second = colors[variable + 1]
    variable = variable + 1
end
```

Comment: The whole idea of using arrays to store the color value is working better in alot of ways :)